# how to make div width fits nested inline images within?

Tags: html, css

I have couple of inline images within a div
I can't get the div to adjust its width to its inline images within 
how do I do it ??

I have tried making the parent div

**display:inline-block,  inline,  float:left**

but none of them work ....

html:

```
<div id="box1">
  <div id="box2">
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <img src="2.jpg">
    <img src="3.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#box1{
width:600px;
overflow:hidden;

} 

#box2{
display:inline-block;
}

#box2 img{
vertical-align:top;
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way I can fix this is get box2 like this  : |

```
#box2{
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

if anyone has any other solution please post away

Answer (score 0):

Doing `float:left` should work - see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VasXf/

Note: I added line breaks between the images with `<br />` which may have been your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need your images to `display: inline-block;` too :)

See: http://jsfiddle.net/VasXf/2/

Comment: thanks somehow when I use my images, it doesn't work on safari :(

Comment: Can you re-test that? I've just launched it in my Safari fine :(